# Application of Geometric distribution to balls into bins

Tags: probability

We need to populate the set $S$ by sampling uniformly at random from a universe of size $2^n$.

Given $n = 3$, and that so far we have added 6 elements to the set, what is the expected number of samples we will need to draw until the set reaches the size of 8?

---

Here is my idea:

X is the random variable that determines the number of samples until we reach the set size of 8. Since it counts the "number of independent trials until success", I think that X follows a binomial distribution $G(p)$, for some $p$. To find $p$ I ask the following question: there are 8 bins (because $n = 3$) and I throw 2 balls, what is the probability $p$ that there will be no collision?

When I throw the first ball, the probability that it will fall into one of the two empty buckets is $\frac{2}{8}$ (6 buckets are already occupied). Then I throw the other ball and its probability of falling into the only remaining empty bucket is $\frac{1}{8}$. Thus, $p = \frac{2}{8} \cdot \frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{32}$. That is, X follows Geometric distribution with this $p$.

Finally, since $E[X] = \frac{1}{p}$ when $X \sim G(p)$, then $E[X] = 32$.

However, that does not get along with my experiments. I wrote a Python program to test this:

```
import random
from statistics import mean

def sample_until_new(n=3, m=1, set_size=6):
    """
    Return the number of trials until success.

    Parameters:
    `n`        maximum integer is 2^n - 1
    `m`        the number of new elements we need to sample
    `set_size` the size of the set at the moment we are looking
               for the new element
    """
    def get_rnd():
        """Sample uniformly at random from [0, 2^n - 1]."""
        return random.randint(0, 2**n - 1)

    # make set of size `set_size`
    S = set()
    while len(S) < set_size:
        c = get_rnd()
        S.update([c])

    # count the trials until we sample the new elements
    new_elems = set()
    tries = 0
    while len(new_elems) < m:
        c = get_rnd()
        tries += 1
        if c not in S:
            new_elems.update([c])

    return tries


X = []                          # X ~ G(p)
for _ in range(10000):
    X.append(sample_until_new(m=2))

E_X = mean(X)

print(f"E[X] = {E_X}")
```

The program says that $E[X] = 12$.

---

Isaiah's answer summarized:

My usage of Geometric distribution was wrong. To use the Geometric distribution, we need to have the probability of success constant over all trials. When we sample a random integer to fill the 7th element of the set $S$, the probability of picking the good one is $\frac{2}{8}$. Then when we're filling the 8th element, the probability of success is $\frac{1}{8}$. So the probability is not constant over all trials.

Instead, we should be looking at the two random variables: $X_1 \sim G(\frac{2}{8})$ describing the number of trials needed to sample the 7th element such that it is good, and $X_2 \sim G(\frac{1}{8})$ describing the number of trials needed to sample the 8th element to be good. The sum of $X_1$ and $X_2$ gives the overall number of trials we need. Thus:

$$E[X_1 + X_2] = E[X_1] + E[X_2] = \frac{8}{2} + \frac{8}{1} = 12.$$

(the first equation is by the linearity of expectation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close; however, you cannot use the binomial distribution here because the probability isn't constant across all trials. As soon as you get one of the two missing items, the probability of a success (getting a missing number) changes as you have already calculated.

Instead, you are looking at the sum of two geometric random variables. Let $X_1$ be a random variable indicating how many trials it takes to get one of the two missing numbers and let $X_2$ represent the number of trials it takes to get the final missing value after obtaining the first one. Then let $X=X_1+X_2$. This gives us the total number of trials it takes to get both missing numbers. I think you can figure out the rest from here. To be clear, your program gets the correct result.